# Dealing with accents and keeping the same font

Tags: fonts, verbatim, accents, typewriter

My LaTeX file contains accents which I cannot format as this text is included automatically. I hence chose to use `\texttt` and `\verb` so that I can display all kind of special characters (see code below). My problem is that the font is the frozen, is there so a way to:
(1) accept any kind of special characters (%,è,à,ü..)
(2) use a given font
(3) not having to format these fonts in the LaTeX way (`\'e`, ...)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvetica}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.1in,%
        left=0.15in,right=0.15in,top=0.15in,bottom=0.35in,%
        footskip=0.85in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\emph{Estimation de la masse grasse}
{\tiny\verb? *Enlevé 1cm au tour de hanche à cause short TeamCanada. Obj:     diminuer % gras?}

\begin{center}
\emph{\texttt{Estimation du V02max et Répartition des plis cutanés}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any tip,

Comment: Have you tried adding the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}` to the preamble? Incidentally, I assume you meant to write `\usepackage{helvet}` rather than `\usepackage{helvetica}`. Incidentally, unless you are willing to encase strings that contain "special" characters -- `%`, `&`, `#`, `^`, `_`, etc -- in `\url` wrappers, you will need to "escape" them by prefixing `\\` to them.

Comment: Incidentally, is switching to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX an option for you? If so, writing `\url{*Enlevé 1cm au tour de hanche à cause short TeamCanada. Obj:      diminuer % gras?}` will produce the correct result. (As you've discovered, this isn't the case with pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mico, I chose the helvetica font (that in include using the corresponding sty file). I cannot escape the characters with '\' because I won't have access to the text, it has to be included automatically. What do the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage{lmodern} do?

Comment: I use a minimal installation of latex. My goal is just to produce basic reports by including some texts plus figures, no math

Comment: By default, LaTeX uses the so-called `OT1` font encoding, in which many "accented" characters are simply absent. The `T1` font encoding, which is of a more recent vintage, provides direct support for many accented characters. The `Latin Modern` font family is a clone of `Computer Modern` that contains many accented characters.

Comment: "I use a minimal installation of latex" -- just how minimal is it? What happens if you change the engine/format combination in your front-end (the editor) from pdflatex to lualatex?

Comment: I am using BasicTex

Comment: @mico: Even with OT1 encoding, the `inputenc` package should do the right thing and map all accented characters to LICRs using combining accents at last. Of course, T1 encoded fonts have their advantages when you have accented characters (e.g., allowing hyphenation).

Answer (score 1):

`\texttt` doesn't improve the printing of problematic input, so it quite useless. All your other examples are unproblematic with the exception of the `%`, and this you can easily avoid by changing its catcode.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.1in,%
        left=0.15in,right=0.15in,top=0.15in,bottom=0.35in,%
        footskip=0.85in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\%=12
\emph{Estimation de la masse grasse}


*Enlevé 1cm au tour de hanche à cause short TeamCanada. Obj:     diminuer % gras?

\emph{Estimation du V02max et Répartition des plis cutanés}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E9}{\'e}

\begin{document}
é
\end{document}
```

You have to look up the character numbers and insert the escape version. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: in fact, I don't know what kind of weird characters are going to be in the text, so I just need some "dummy printing", so that these characters be simply displayed

Comment: @XavierPrudent In that case I would recommend as already mentioned to use lualatex.

Comment: ok, thanks, and what is the difference between lualatex and BasicTex ?